# opening email with javascript on iphone

Tags: javascript, iphone, email

I have a website that format the subject of the email that the user need to send. Then I open the client default email with mailto: function in javascript and they write their email and send it. It work everywhere I have tested it except with iPhone can someone tell me why, please.

This the code I use for opening the default email:

```
    var email = 'email@dot.com';
    var subject = 'the subject';
    var bodyemail = 'the body';

    var mailto_link = 'mailto:' + email + '?subject=' + subject + '&body=' + encodeURI(bodyemail);

    win = window.open(mailto_link, 'emailWindow');

    if (win && win.open && !win.closed) win.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't open the mailto link in a new window, just set the current window's href to the link.

```
window.location.href = mailto_link;
```